# Isolate css scope

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For a very mysterious reason, I have to limit the scope of a css file only to an element:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="one.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="first-container">
        </div>

        <div id="second-container">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="two.css">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rules in `one.css` should be applied as usual, while the rules in `two.css` should be scoped to the `div#second-container` only.

That is exactly what the attribute `scoped`  attribute should do: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/style.html#style.attrs.scoped , but is not currently supported (and it will never be) http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped .

I've tried to isolate scope with a regex (CSS are 10K+ lines minified), but it didn't work out well.

Any solution (or dirty workaround) for a strange use case like this?

I can use one of these way:

- *one shot solution*: some `sed` magic on `two.css` which prepends everything with `div#sed-container`
- *server side solution*: some magic with php
- *client side solution*: some magic with js, without making extra sever call (i.e.: AJAX)

Comment: have u seen this library http://arleym.com/scopedcss/static/jquery.scoped.js and demo page of its implementation http://arleym.com/scopedcss/static/index2.html

Comment: I cannot use AJAX :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sass` and `Nesting`

```
// .scss
#second-container {
    @import 'two';
}
```

Comment: Perfect and easy. (Side note: Sass, not SASS, says the creator.)

Comment: but `two` is a `css`, doesn't `@import` work with `scss` only?

Comment: @marka.thore you can just change the extension to `.scss`

Comment: It says: CSS import directives may only be used at the root of a document

Answer (score 3):

It might be a little complicated but this comes to my mind:

1) Create invisible iframe element anc copy content of div to it

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.style.display = 'none';
i.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + document.querySelector('#secondDiv').innerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

2) Apply style in iframe

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
frames['iframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

3) [Inline style of html in iframe](http://devintorr.es/blog/2010/05/26/turn-css-rules-into-inline-style-attributes-using-jquery/).

4) Copy it back to div from iframe.

Answer (score 1):

try this: add an extra id to the element, and make the isolated css to style that element using that extra id, in case the styling does not take effect, try adding `!important` to that particular line in your isolated css. e.g : `height:0px !important;`

Comment: that's exactly the question. How to isolate the rules in `two.css` without manually editing all the css?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [Shadow-Dom](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom) aswell:

```js
const component = document.querySelector('#component');
const host = document.querySelector('#host');
const shadow = host.attachShadow({'mode': 'closed'});
shadow.appendChild(component);
```

```css
#component {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css' />

<div id="component">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>

  <button class='btn btn-primary'>I get bootstrap 4 css </button>
</div>

<div id="host"></div>
<br />
<button class='btn btn-primary'>I get bootstrap 2 css </button>
```

## This wont work in every Browser: Have a look [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1).